# Jquery filter rows by detach/append

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am aware of hide/show, but I'm wondering how I can remove rows from the DOM using Jquery's detach and append them back in.   I would like to live filter the html table by an input.

This code seems to work on every other keystroke

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var tablerows;

    $('#filter').on("input", function () {

        let term = $(this).val().trim();

        if (tablerows) {
            $(tablerows).appendTo('#main')
            tablerows = null;
        } else {
            tablerows = $("#main tr:not(:first-child, :icontains('" + term + "'))").detach();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: why detach? why not just hide them?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the "alternating behaviour" is due to this logic:

```
if (tablerows) { 
  /* 
  The problem is here, in that you are always adding the current 
  tablerows back into the table
  */
}
else {
  /*
  ..
  */
}
```

For this approach to work as required, you'll need to extend you logic in the `if (tablerows)` case to ensure that, the current filter terms are not contained in what ever `tablerows` you currently have. If the current terms are not present in the currently detached `tablerows`, then at this point you'd reintroduce those into your table:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var tablerows;

  $('#filter').on("input", function() {

    let term = $(this).val().trim();

    if (tablerows) {

      /* 
      Also note that an empty term string needs to be accounted for
      which the :contains selector won't account for, hence the !term
      */
      if ($(":contains('" + term + "')", tablerows) === false || !term)
      {
        /*
        No match for filter terms so add tablerows back to table 
        */
        $(tablerows).appendTo('#main')
        tablerows = null;
      }
    } else {

      /* 
      There was a typo here, it should read :contains (not :icontains)
      */
      tablerows = $("#main tr:not(:first-child, :contains('" + 
          term + "'))").detach();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<table id="main">
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bar</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input id="filter" />
```

Comment: Hi Dacre, thanks for your reply, but I'm having trouble getting this to work correctly.  Will this work on tables with multiple columns?  http://jsfiddle.net/hxcnwst7/1/